# c, if statement doesn't work properly

Tags: c, if-statement, macros

I did this simple program but my if statement doesn't work properly.
Here my code:

```
void SCRIVI_RUOTA(int s, int i, int c)
 {
    _CONFIG_DRIVE_PORT_OUTPUT_VALUE(C, (segK|segL|segM), 0, (PORT_SRE_SLOW | PORT_DSE_HIGH));  // this switch off all my LEDS

s=0;
i=0;
c=0;
    if(s==1)
        _CONFIG_DRIVE_PORT_OUTPUT_VALUE(C, (segK), (segK), (PORT_SRE_SLOW | PORT_DSE_HIGH));  // this switch on my LED N° 1
    if(i==1)
        _CONFIG_DRIVE_PORT_OUTPUT_VALUE(C, (segM), (segM), (PORT_SRE_SLOW | PORT_DSE_HIGH));  // this switch on my LED N° 2
    if(c==1)
        _CONFIG_DRIVE_PORT_OUTPUT_VALUE(C, (segL), (segL), (PORT_SRE_SLOW | PORT_DSE_HIGH));  // this switch on my LED N° 3
```

}

well, I can put s, i, c, equals to 0 or 1 but the if statement is always execute and my LEDS turn on in any case.

if I delete the switch on command inside the if statement the LED doesn't turns on (and this means that there are not other functions that make conflicts forcing the LEDs to high).
if I put an else after the if statements that switch OFF the LEDs all the LEDs switch OFF. It sounds like if the if and else statement doesn't exist and the last command on the LED is execute.
Is it possible exist functions or macros or something else that ignore the if statement?

Comment: you set s,i,c = 0. so you ignore all values passed in. Why are you doing that?

Comment: that's just a test, in real program I don't put s, i, c =0 here but the variables  are passed by the function

Comment: try doing this `if(s==1) {_CONFIG.....}`. Ie wrap {} around the condition statement. That macro might be doing something wierd

Comment: and you are sure you have s==1 and not s=1

Comment: Also, name the macro without the leading underscore.   Identifiers with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for use by the implementation

Comment: I wrapped the macro and now works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

It is likely your macro expands into multiple statements, and is not wrapped with `do .. while(0)`.

Surround the macro with `{}` in your `if` statements.

```
if(s==1) {
    _CONFIG_DRIVE_PORT_OUTPUT_VALUE(...);
}
//...
```

As noted in the comments, the original macro can be considered broken, and should be fixed.

Assuming the macro is defined like:

```
#define _CONFIG_DRIVE_PORT_OUTPUT_VALUE(ref, pins, value, chars) \
    GPIO##ref##_PIDR &= ~(pins);                                 \
    GPIO##ref##_PDOR = ((GPIO##ref##_PDOR & ~(pins)) | (value)); \
    GPIO##ref##_PDDR |= (pins);
```

It should be changed to be this instead:

```
#define _CONFIG_DRIVE_PORT_OUTPUT_VALUE(ref, pins, value, chars) \
    do {                                                         \
    GPIO##ref##_PIDR &= ~(pins);                                 \
    GPIO##ref##_PDOR = ((GPIO##ref##_PDOR & ~(pins)) | (value)); \
    GPIO##ref##_PDDR |= (pins);                                  \
    } while(0)
```

If the macros were fixed, then your original code would work unmodified.

Comment: ....  or change the macro to wrap everything in `do { .... }while (0)`.

Comment: See [Why use apparently meaningless do-while and if-else statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154136/12711)

Comment: @Peter: I doubt the asker authored the macros, but yes, multi-statement macros should be wrapped.

Comment: @jxh - I wouldn't exclude the possibility that she authored the macros.  My comment was more along the lines of something she could report to the author of the macros as a flaw.

Comment: Yes - if the macros aren't wrapped, they're broken.  Whoever is responsible for them should fix them.

Comment: @Peter: Simone has a beard.  ;-)

Comment: @JeffLearman - so does the lady who lives next door to me  :-)

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Answer updated, but many style guides mandate that the body of a `if`, `while`, etc. should always have `{` .. `}`.

Comment: The thing is, it costs nothing to wrap the macros and then they work whether or not the user follows the style guide. I think it's important because the macro is designed to hide the fact that there are multiple statements, so they should be designed to work exactly like a single statement.  And as far as style guides go, at least one important project's style guide explicitly forbids putting braces around single lines controlled by an `if` or `else` (the Linux Kernel style).  I don't agree with that guidance, but I'm not a Linux Kernel contributor, so they don't really care what I think.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I am not disputing the benefits of wrapping macros with multiple statements. I believe just as you do. I am just pointing out that there are mitigations available that would have avoided the issue encountered by the OP.